# Обновление ComboBoxItem при нажатии на ToggleButton

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется `ComboBox`, в котором хранится список доступных портов.
На данный момент для обновления используется отдельная кнопка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас необходимо избавиться от нее, и реализовать обновление содержимого `ComboBox` по нажатию на `ToggleButton` этого `ComboBox`.
Возможно ли такое реализовать? И если возможно, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

обновлять в обработчике события DropDownOpened этого ComboBox'а ?
оно возникает при нажатии на кнопку раскрытия выпадающего списка, но до того как этот список будет отрисован.

Comment: спасибо, заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы пользуетесь MVVM, правильный подход такой: ваш список портов должен быть актуален в *любой* момент.

Для этого вы в VM кладёте `ObservableCollection<PortVM>` (ну или хотя бы `ObservableCollection<string>`), и обновляете её.

Для обновления можно либо подписаться на WMI-сообщения, как показано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735274/276994), либо просто проводить поллинг списка каждую секунду:

```
while (true)
{
    var ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames().OrderBy(name => name);
    PortList.Clear();
    foreach (var port in ports)
        PortList.Add(port);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Ну и в XAML

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PortList}"/>
```

В таком варианте список будет обновляться даже когда ваш комбобокс раскрыт.